# Tezos Improvement Proposals

Tags: untagged

Is there a website tracking "Tezos Improvement Proposals" similar to what exist in some other open sourced projects ?

I am aware of conversation channels to discuss actual amendment proposals on kialo like this

https://www.kialo.com/tezos-protocol-amendment-1-25295/25295.0/25295.0

as well as the channel where all sorts of technical issues and bug for the tezos codebase are reported/discussed on gitlab

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues

however is there some other public location where other more general improvement proposals could be referenced and discussed ? Something similar to Bitcoin BIP perhaps

https://github.com/bitcoin/bips

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A group of developers (including myself) have started a repo that we hope would be used for Tezos Improvement Proposals (or TIPs). Although this is not official (and I don't know of any official repos doing this), this could be used as a starting point. https://gitlab.com/tips2/TIPs

Answer (score 3):

There is a section outlined for proposals on the block explorer: Tzscan.io

[image: tzscan block explorer]

Comment: those proposals are amendment proposals which have already reached the stage where they are implemented and ready to be voted upon. What i am talking about in my question is more like "long term" type of improvement proposals, where the community can reach consensus that this would be "a good thing to have" even though there is no immediate plan to have it implemented just yet.

Comment: You mean a consolidated "road map" similar to what has been mentioned here? https://www.reddit.com/r/tezos/comments/ahr1n4/updateroadmaps_by_grantees/

Answer (score 0):

https://gitlab.com/tzip/tzip appears to be the defacto location for "TeZos Improvement Proposals".